# Remove item from the list, if it exists in other lists

Tags: c#, list

I have a class:

```
[Serializable()]
public class Computer
{

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("Id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("Cost")]
    public double Cost { get; set; }

    public string NameCost
    {
        get
        {
            return Name + " " + Cost.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
    }
}
```

And i have three lists. One of them contains computers with minimal cost, another  have computers with maximum cost. Last list that contains all the elements. I need to remove in the list of all elements, except those that exist in the other two lists. You have any idea? help, plz. Have a nice day!

Comment: Why not give Computer a `MinCost` and `MaxCost`?  Then you don't have to deal with multiple lists.

Answer (score 2):

Not very efficient but should work:

```
listWithAllPC = listWithAllPC
    .Where(pc => listWithMinCostPC.Any(minPC => pc.Id == minPC.Id)
              && listWithMaxCostPC.Any(maxPC => pc.Id == maxPC.Id))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: @Sayse, I'm sure that it works. What I meant was, Tim is a C# Gold Badge holder and he has used so many methods and All I did was just two lines. So I was afraid that I wasn't missing something

Comment: @AmitJoki: what have you tried, what didn't work? I have changed the code to check the `Id` instead of the `NameCost` property. You haven't even specified what a duplicate is at all.

Comment: As you can see, I'm checking if the maxList and minList **contains** the item and if it returns true, it will be removed. Now the `.Contains` itself checks the item's equality  etc...

Comment: For example take this:  `var all = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c" }; var a = new List<string>() { "a" }; all.RemoveAll(u => a.Contains(u));` now `all`  will only contain b and c. The same holds true for custom objects

Comment: String overrides `Equals` whereas your class does not. That's why i don't use `Contains` (which uses `Equals` implicitly) but `Enumerable.Any`. Of course there are other way, overriding `Equals` (+`GetHashCode`) and using `Contains` or a custom `IEqualityComparer<Computer>` etc..

Comment: Yes but the point is, don't the equal each other? I'm sure `.Equals` is not designed just for primitive data types.I think it will also be able to handle custom objects with custom properties.  I'm not so good as you are, so asking for a clarification

Comment: @AmitJoki: if you don't override `Equals` `Contains` will use `Object.Equals`   which just compares references. read: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx .NET does not automatically compare  your properties (as it does with anonymous types).

Comment: And in my case the references differ I suppose

Comment: @AmitJoki: this is the same reference even if there are two variables: `var pc1 = new Computer(); var pc2 = pc1;`. These are two different references: `var pc1 = new Computer(); var pc2 = new Computer();`

Answer (score -1):

```
var idList = list1.Union(list2).Select(x => x.Id).ToList();
list3.RemoveAll(x => !idList.Contains(x.Id));
```